# convert 9x9 array into 9 (3x3) array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

convert 9x9 array into 9 (3x3) array in javascript?
i have written the code, but its not pushing the 3x3's into separate array.
i want 9 3x3 arrays

```js
let array =
  [
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
[2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7],
[3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8],
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3],
[5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7, 2, 3, 1],
[6, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8, 3, 1, 2],
[7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
[8, 9, 7, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4],
[9, 7, 8, 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 5]
  ];

let final=[];

let row = [0,1,2];
let col = [0,1,2];
let counter = 0;

for ( let i = 0 ; i <= array.length - 1 ; i += 3 )
{

  for(let j = 0 ; j <= array.length - 1 ; j += 3 )
  { 
final.push([]);

row.forEach( ele1 => {
  final[counter].push([])
  
  col.forEach( ele2 => {
    final[counter][ele1].push(array[ele1+i][ele2+j]);
  })
  
})

counter+=1;
  }

}

console.log(final)
```

Comment: don't see anything wrong with what you have

Comment: Your code snippet is already a 9 (3x3) array, or that's not the arrangement you want, can you post the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array using map function and check for the index values to break into arrays as required.

```js
let myArr =[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
            [2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7],
            [3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8],
            [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3],
            [5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7, 2, 3, 1],
            [6, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8, 3, 1, 2],
            [7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            [8, 9, 7, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4],
            [9, 7, 8, 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 5]];

let newArr = convertTo3x3(myArr);
console.log(newArr);


function convertTo3x3(myArr){
  let array3x3 = [];
  
  myArr.map((row, rIndex) => {
    let tempArr = [];
    let row3 = [];
    
    row.map((item, lIndex) => {
      // convert each row to 3x3 rows
      if(lIndex % 3 == 0){
        // reset row3 for new 3x3 arr on every 1st item of 3x3
        row3 = [];
      }
      
      row3.push(item);
      
      if(lIndex % 3 == 2){
        // push 3x3 row to tempArr on every 3rd item of 3x3
        tempArr.push(row3);
      }
    });
    
    array3x3.push(tempArr);
    
  });
  
  return array3x3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work fine, but if you want a more javascriptey code, that performs worse, here you go.

```js
let array = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7],
  [3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8],
  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3],
  [5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 7, 2, 3, 1],
  [6, 4, 5, 9, 7, 8, 3, 1, 2],
  [7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [8, 9, 7, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4],
  [9, 7, 8, 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 5],
  ];
let final = [];
array
  .reduce((a, c) => {
    const chunk = (arr, n) =>
    arr.length ? [arr.slice(0, n), ...chunk(arr.slice(n), n)] : [];
    return [...a, ...chunk(c, 3)];
    }, [])
  .map((el, i) => {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      final = [...final, [el]];
    } else {
      final[Math.floor(i / 3)] = [...final[Math.floor(i / 3)], el];
    }
   });
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to do too much. Make it difficult to understand.

I would first break it up. Write a simple function than knows how to take an array-of-arrays and return an arbitrary rectangular selection from it. Something like this, that's easy to test:

```js
/**
 * Snip a rectangular section of an array of arrays (ragged, 2D array).
 * The returned array-of-arrys will ALWAYS be the specified size, padded
 * with 'undefined' values to the specified size.
 *
 * @param {Object[][]} arr - An array of arrays (ragged 2D array)
 * @param {number} row - Origin row: {row,col} denotes the upper-left corner of the rectangle to snip
 * @param {number} col - Origin column: {row,col} denotes the upper-left corner of the rectangle to snip
 * @param {number} nrows - Number of rows to snip
 * @param {number} ncols - Nunber of columns to snip
 *
 * @returns {Object[][]}
 */
function snip(arr, row, col, nrows, ncols ) {
  const selection = [];
  
  for ( let r = row, i = 0 ; r < row+nrows ; ++r, ++i ) {
    selection[i] = [];
    
    const tmp = arr[r] ?? [];
    for ( let c = col, j = 0 ; c < col+ncols ; ++c, ++j ) {
      selection[i][j] = tmp[c];
    }
    
  }
  
  return selection;
}
```

Once you have that, then chopping up your larger array-of-arrays into 3x3 arrays is easy.

This code starts at the top left corner or your 9x9 array and returns a flat list containing 9 separate 3x3 arrays, chopped out left-to-right and top-to-bottom:

```js
final = [];

for ( let x = 0 ; x < 9; x += 3 ) {
  for ( let y = 0 ; y < 9 ; y += 3 ) {
    // (x,y) denotes the top left corner of the desired sub-array
    final.push( snip(arr, x,y, 3,3 ) );
  }
}
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it is easy to test, and
.
.
.
It's flexible. It can handle a source array of any size, and you can chop it up into subarrays of any size and in any order, whatever you see fit to do.

Comment: I am so sorry guys, i was actually testing some other code .  This code seems to work perfect. Thank you everyone for your efforts